# REST API best practices for CRUD operation that triggers a long running task

Tags: c#, api, rest, hangfire

In my architecture I have a set of entities that when created/updated trigger a long running task that performs a long recalculation (around 6-7 minutes).

Actually I trigger the task in Hangfire and I want to pass a token to the client that can be used to query another endpoint to monitor the long running task progress. What's best way to do it?

Is this okay or there are better/standard ways to present the result to the client?

```
{
   "data": {
      "id": 2,
      "dateCreated": "2021-02-11T17:10:17.16",
      "userCreated": "",
      "dateModified": "2021-02-11T17:10:17.16",
      "userModified": "",
      "code": "SPEC-002",
      "name": "My entity",
      "_links": [
        // HATEOAS links
      ],
      "_tasks": [
        // long running tasks info
      ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I would tackle this the following way:

1. When the request is made, return `202 Accepted`.
2. In the response, return a link with the up-to-date status. I typically use a `Link` header for this, but you could also use a HAL link.

Comment: mmm... in my case the long running task is a sort of "side effect" due to the insert/update request; would not it be more correct to return `201` or `204` and the link in header (or as a HAL)?

Comment: If you feel it makes more semantic sense that you 'created a long running task', vs: 'you did an operation, it hasn't completed yet, see the status here', then this seems pretty reasonable. In that case I don't think HAL really prescribes how you should format that kind of thing. To me they would just be regular properties.

Comment: If it makes sense to you to have the 'long running task info' on a separate resource, you could still link there ofc, and you could also put the data in `_embedded`.

Comment: Thank you very much!